# What is the correct CMOS setting?

Tags: circuit-analysis, cmos

I'm having trouble understanding the correct configuration, because the CKT below has mosfet channel n symbology, but when I see the configuration it looks like p channel connections and looking at the symbology it gets a little confusing, because it seems that it reversed the upper position to the lower one .

[image]

based on the symbology plus the configuration, I understand I have to calculate the circuit as if it were channel p to find the ID, gm, is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That transistor is *P* channel. It does not have n-channel symbology.

It's drawn without a body connection, and the arrow points *from* the source toward the gate, which is consistent with the second-to-last schematic symbol from the right in your post. Further evidence:

- V_t is -1 V. If it's indeed enhancement-mode (which is fairly common), then a negative threshold voltage implies P-type
- The source is at the terminal that has the higher voltage between the two ends of the channel
- As drawn and labeled, Vds is negative

The whole circuit is drawn upside-down compared to the standard convention; it should be straightforward to redraw it right-side-up with the same components. Here's a quick attempt with just the flip tool of an image editor:

[image]